# Repeat field if field bellow is empty

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tab delim file

```
1A      21      .        SMO     gene_start
1A      3940    .        SMO     gene_end
1A      52236   .        LOC105758527    gene_start
1A      55001   0.469590
1A      65001   0.067909
1A      75001   0.220712
1A      78812   .        LOC105758527    gene_end
1A      79831   .        LOC100218126    gene_start
1A      85001   0.174872
1A      93700   .        LOC100218126    gene_end
1A      96312   .        LOC105758528    gene_start
1A      98792   .        LOC105758528    gene_end
1A      115136  .        LOC105758529    gene_start
1A      125001  0.023420
1A      126187  .        LOC105758529    gene_end

...
```

and I need to fill in the empty fields in column 4 by repeating the with what is right above it.

```
1A      21      .        SMO     gene_start
1A      3940    .        SMO     gene_end
1A      52236   .        LOC105758527    gene_start
1A      55001   0.469590 LOC105758527
1A      65001   0.067909 LOC105758527
1A      75001   0.220712 LOC105758527
1A      78812   .        LOC105758527    gene_end
1A      79831   .        LOC100218126    gene_start
1A      85001   0.174872 LOC100218126
1A      93700   .        LOC100218126    gene_end
1A      96312   .        LOC105758528    gene_start
1A      98792   .        LOC105758528    gene_end
1A      115136  .        LOC105758529    gene_start
1A      125001  0.023420 LOC105758529
1A      126187  .        LOC105758529    gene_end

...
```

I'm doing

```
awk 'NF==5{v=$4;print} NF==3{print v,$0}' file
```

but I'm getting this

```
1A      21      .       SMO     gene_start
1A      3940    .       SMO     gene_end
1A      52236   .       LOC105758527    gene_start
LOC105758527 1A 55001   0.469590
LOC105758527 1A 65001   0.067909
LOC105758527 1A 75001   0.220712
1A      78812   .       LOC105758527    gene_end
1A      79831   .       LOC100218126    gene_start
LOC100218126 1A 85001   0.174872
1A      93700   .       LOC100218126    gene_end
1A      96312   .       LOC105758528    gene_start
1A      98792   .       LOC105758528    gene_end
1A      115136  .       LOC105758529    gene_start
LOC105758529 1A 125001  0.023420
1A      126187  .       LOC105758529    gene_end
```

Can't tell what to change

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign your stored value to the "*missing*" field:

```
awk 'NF==5{v=$4}NF==3{$4=v}1' OFS="\t" file
```

The `1` at the end is just a shortcut to avoid using the print statement.

In `awk` when a condition gets matched the default action is to print the input line.

```
$ echo "test" |awk '1'
```

Is equivalent to:

```
echo "test"|awk '1==1'

echo "test"|awk '{if (1==1){print}}'
```

That's because `1` will be always true

Comment: Probably more equivalent to `awk '1!=0'`

Answer (score 1):

Some like this:

```
awk '!$4 {$0=$0 FS t} {t=$4} 1' "OFS=\t" file
1A      21      .        SMO     gene_start
1A      3940    .        SMO     gene_end
1A      52236   .        LOC105758527    gene_start
1A      55001   0.469590 LOC105758527
1A      65001   0.067909 LOC105758527
1A      75001   0.220712 LOC105758527
1A      78812   .        LOC105758527    gene_end
1A      79831   .        LOC100218126    gene_start
1A      85001   0.174872 LOC100218126
1A      93700   .        LOC100218126    gene_end
1A      96312   .        LOC105758528    gene_start
1A      98792   .        LOC105758528    gene_end
1A      115136  .        LOC105758529    gene_start
1A      125001  0.023420 LOC105758529
1A      126187  .        LOC105758529    gene_end
```

Or same some shorter:

```
awk '!$4?$0=$0FS t:t=$4' OFS="\t" file
```

Does forth filed not exists: false, store `$4` to `t`
Does forth filed not exists: true, add `t` to line

Shorter version of Juans version

```
awk 'NF==5?v=$4:$4=v' OFS="\t" file
```

Comment: That last script would fail when $4 has a numeric value that evaluates to zero and it's setting OFS to `t` instead of `\t` since the shell would eat the ```\``` but you're using FS (a blank char) instead of OFS anyway and never setting FS. In general you should avoid making the print dependent on the result of a condition unless necessary (or at a minimum useful in some way other than saving 3 chars).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the field-separator tabs are present even when the fields are empty like with any normal CSV or TSV file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $4==""{$4=prev} {prev=$4} 1' file
1A      21      .       SMO     gene_start
1A      3940    .       SMO     gene_end
1A      52236   .       LOC105758527    gene_start
1A      55001   0.469590        LOC105758527
1A      65001   0.067909        LOC105758527
1A      75001   0.220712        LOC105758527
1A      78812   .       LOC105758527    gene_end
1A      79831   .       LOC100218126    gene_start
1A      85001   0.174872        LOC100218126
1A      93700   .       LOC100218126    gene_end
1A      96312   .       LOC105758528    gene_start
1A      98792   .       LOC105758528    gene_end
1A      115136  .       LOC105758529    gene_start
1A      125001  0.023420        LOC105758529
1A      126187  .       LOC105758529    gene_end
```

Comment: For me this does not give the result you post, just same as input without added $4.  Just copy and past OP request and your solution.

Comment: Then you must be using input that doesn't have all the field separators present as I said is required: `Assuming all the field-separator tabs are present...`. If I copy/paste the OPs sample then all spaces are blank chars and we know that's not correct since she told us the input is tab-separated and I don't think the missing tabs from  the end of the samples is correct either. I expect in her real data she simply has a TSV with empty fields rather than different numbers of fields per line. If I'm wrong, she has other answers...

Comment: ... though all the other answers will fail if/when she has a blank char in a field as they aren't setting FS to `\t` and are relying on the default FS being good enough AND on the separators between the empty fields being missing.